# Installing Ubuntu 14.04.4 on VSphere 6.0u1b

Tags: 14.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu 14.04.4 on VSphere 6.0u1b.  Hardware version 11.

I get server installed and i can access console, use the command line, all seems fine.  I installed ubuntu desktop, and when the server restarts, although the mouse works to let me put the cursor in the password field, when I login, the mouse no longer works or appears to work extremely slowly.  Hence I cannot do anything on the desktop, XRDP does not work either (the Alt-combo keys work to switch to command line, which works fine) and I disabled firewall.  With firewall disabled, XRDP doesn't work, nor does they mouse.

Has anyone had issues with ubuntu 14.04 and vSphere 6.0 (hardware version 11) ?

Please help - :)

Thanks,